# Is there a generic way to close an HTML tag?

Tags: html, tags, xss

I am testing a web app for XSS vulnerabilities and I want to find out if it is possible for an attacker to close a preceding HTML tag without knowing or caring about what it is.

So suppose the preceding tag (unknown to the attacker) is `<span>` . Is it possible for the attacker to do something like

`</>` <-- close preceding tag (in this case `<span>`) `<insert attack here>`

Comment: The answer is almost certainly no, but surely the attacker would know what tag it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there isn't … but if you want to allow some HTML while defending against XSS you shouldn't use any approach other then parsing the HTML to a DOM, passing every element and attribute past a whitelist, and then serialising it back to HTML yourself.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no generic way to close a tag, but an attacker could just stack a few common tag endings, for example:

```
</div></span></p></table>
```

The code would not be valid in any way, but the browser would try to make the best out of it by ignoring tags that doesn't apply (the `div` and `table` tags in this case), or implicitly create matching starting tags (for the `p` tag in this case).

The end result would be that the attacker would break out of one or more elements in most cases, possibly adding a few empty elements on the way.

Answer (score 1):

A better and more lightweight approach is to just HTML encode all your data. Converting < to &lt; and > to &gt; effectively renders the injected html useless.

Additionally, if you're already in an XSS situation, the attacker could figure it out via javascript, however I would imagine this approach is not very useful given you've already been exploited if javascript is executing.

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="the-one-im-looking-for"><span id="my-attack-element" style="display:none;">&nbsp;</span>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.alert(document.getElementById("my-attack-element").parentNode.tagName);
</script>
</div>
</html>
```

I like spamming end tags approach...